# AndroidStudio - Apps built on ARM processors are functionally different from Intel with same codebase

Tags: android-studio, arm, google-places-api, intel

This week I received a new work laptop MBP M3 Pro. I have been using a MBP i7 for the last few years. I am currently working on a project that completely works when ran from the Intel machine but does not when ran from the ARM machine.

To be more specific, the app builds and runs on an emulator API 28-31 seemingly fine. This is also true for a physical S22 Ultra. I had previously implemented Places API 3.3.0 (latest at the time of writing this) inside of an AutoCompleteTextView. This is working as expected when built from an Intel machine. Using the identical codebase on an ARM machine, this library does NOT work. No errors in console, nothing to share, its as if the functionality is completely missing.

Both machines are running the latest AndroidStudio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2 except that they are running the build best supported for its architecture.

Understandably the binary and support libraries should be different so I built a debug APK from the intel and from the ARM. I used the APK Analyzer in android studio to compare them both of which resulted in very minor differences in a few class dex files. After dumping the APK, dex2jar the questionable class dex's and comparing source of each, i cannot find any textual differences in any of the classes. From what I can see they are the same thing.

I have yet to find any discussion anywhere on apps not working built from ARM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By "library" you mean a Java/Kotlin library in JAR/aar format or a native library in .so format? For the first there shouldn't be a different between ARM and x86. Only the Android version may have an effect if a code part works or not. Sometimes also the used phone model you run the code on has an impact.

Comment: @Robert yes, i am referring to Java/Kotlin libraries. Nevertheless, testing on the same physical device between both machines, when ran from the ARM machine places does not work and ran from the Intel it works fine.

Comment: Then the difference is something else like the Android version or a certain configuration. BTW: you forgot to tell what is going wrong and my be post the stacktrace from logcat.